# JPA Repository - Query

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

How to get by Spring data jpa repository 1 latest entry of table by id ( i tried   findTopOrderByIdDesc(); ) and x of items from specific date and earlier (could not figure out how to define it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For retrieving the latest entry in spring-data your can use the following method declaration
`findOneByIdOrderById(Long id)` or `findOneByIdOrderByDate(Long id)`

For finding x items for specific `Date`(considering date is a property of your jpa managed entity)

`findTopxByDateAfter/Before(@Param("date") Date)` or `findFirstxByDateAfter/Before(@Param("date") Date)`

where x is a number.

Take a look at the reference [spring-data-documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for more info

Comment: On first i ser that i should provid e An id. But how if i wany to have only the latest? And thanks for this solution with date.

Comment: orderByDate suffix should help you